# Does anyone have available the file structure spec for the Palm OS 5 tasks database?

Tags: palm-os

I'm referring to the OS 5 tasks database (with e.g. repeating tasks)--not the ToDo database that preceded it.  At CPAN there are Palm::PDB and Palm::ToDo.  Palm::ToDO is for the older form of the tasks database.